# How to create Azure AlertRule programmatically

Tags: java, python, azure

Is it possible to create an Azure VM AlertRule using either Java or Python? I do not see any documentation in the SDK for either language.

An acceptable answer shows code snippet in either language and does not suggest the usage of the Portal or Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bearrito,
As far as I know, currently there is not SDK for Python and Java about to create Azure VM alert rule. But we could use Azure REST API to create this rule.
Please refer to this document.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510366.aspx

Meanwhile, I recommend you use the certificate to authenticate your application. Please refer to this page to create the certificate and upload to Azure Portal.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert Any update or questions, please let me know.

Comment: I agree that as of the time of comment there was no mechanism in either language.